# Don't consider post owner decisions when serving edit bans

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, suggested-edits, edit-ban

I'm looking at a **user** whose edit suggestions simply consist of **unnecessary** bold **formatting**. Some of **these edits** are getting **rejected**, correctly, but the vast **majority** of their **edits** that are **getting approved** are all decisions by the **owners** of the posts being edited, either `overruling` any and all **third-party reviewer** decisions regardless of **how many** reject votes an edit receives, or **immediately committing** the edit before **anyone else** has a chance to `reject` it.

It's nice that these post owners are accepting formatting edits graciously, but when the editor is making **poor** formatting **edits** claiming them to be **improvements**, their naïve decisions actually **encourage** the **editor** to **continue making** these poor edits in **spite** of other reviewers **repeatedly** thumbing them **down**.

Similarly, `users` making **appropriate** edits that get approved by **other reviewers** but `rejected` by **post owners** can get `banned` from making further **edits** when they **shouldn't be**. This usually happens when the **post owner** doesn't **understand** the principles `behind` the **site**, and thinks it's not OK for **other users** to be **editing** their **posts**.

I'm **not** proposing **removing** this `feature` entirely, because it's not the fault of the post owner — in most cases, they don't know better. But if their decisions are **protecting bad editors** from rejections and bans, or `causing good editors` to be **banned** from making further **edits**, I'm proposing that the `system` simply **not consider** owner decisions for the purposes of determining **edit bans**. Edits with **no other decision** except by the **owner** should be `ignored`.

Comment: **P.S.** This will **never, ever** get **old**.

Comment: `Downvoted` for lack of `backticks`.

Comment: **OMG**, `my` **eyes** !! I want to ignore the post owner's decision and fix the poor formatting of this post.

Comment: This proposal seems like it could have significant unintended effects, and it addresses a pretty narrow problem.  (If you see a user who is repeatedly making bad edits that are getting accepted by post owners, would flagging to notify the moderators be an acceptable workaround?)

Comment: @D.W.: Moderators can't do much directly to address the issue. We can't issue edit bans manually, for one thing.

Comment: Moderators can now issue edit bans, which makes this less of a problem. Still it's a problem nevertheless.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn do you mean *suggested edit bans* or did I miss a memo?

Comment: @Jon Clements: Considering this entire feature request is about post owner decisions on suggested edits, yeah probably.

Answer (score 12):

A crucial question here is which reason we use for giving post authors their edit veto:

- because *we believe them to be **correct in all respects** about how their post should look*, or
- because *it's their post and **they're responsible for how it looks**, and should therefore have some right to choose even stupid things*

I submit that the former idea is the reason this has been declined, but that that interpretation is illogical. It should be fairly clear from the amount of first-post edits that need to be made on all sites that very many authors *don't* know how their posts should look. Some never learn, and keep on posting their signatures, their undifferentiated quotes and code, their messed-up accidentally-inlined HTML, their meaningless tag selections, or their backticks for emphasis all through their hundreds or thousands of posts. Since the beginning, SE has encouraged editing, and corrected callow posters who were taken aback by others editing their posts. Pretending that the reason we give authors edit veto is because they are guaranteed to edit their own posts better than others can is doublethink.

We should continue to allow authors to, if necessary, override most editing norms and produce (or approve the production of) terrible posts if they are absolutely set on that. But that doesn't mean we should give any deference to their judgement in terms of the fitness of edit suggesters to make edits. A suggestion that's approved by the post author isn't approved because they are as generally competent and reliable as a ♦ mod, but because they have more of a say *as the author* than a normal 2k editor/reviewer.

Comment: Exactly my point. You can have an entire posse of trusted reviewers follow the same user around rejecting all their edits, or you can have a completely different set of individuals rejecting each edit, but as long as the same clueless post owner approves them then all of the reviewer rejections will be overridden and their effects completely nullified. A post owner should be (and is) held responsible for their own edits and their own reviews, but not for someone else's suggested edits.

Comment: not enough `backticks`

Answer (score -6):

I *disagree* because the author is actually -- in general -- the definitive **authority** on *whether an edit is pertinent*. <sup>I believe this was the original reason why</sup> we gave authors more decision making power on suggested edits.

## However,

***don't take this as to mean that we* support** *unnecessary* **typography *edits.*** As you noted they are a bad practice -- but we can't prevent people from making [bad-decisions](/questions/tagged/bad-decisions). It would be better to `fix such posts` and approach the OP so they can learn from *their* mistake**s**<sup>.</sup>

Comment: I believe you're confusing the author's *right to expression in their post* with the author's *fitness to judge suitable edits* here. See my answer for a more detailed argument.

Comment: @NathanTuggy not really, I said "pertinent": whether the edit is an improvement of their post or not. Even simple typography can change the perception of what's being conveyed.

Comment: It certainly can, but, in the end, are we giving authors the right to use typography more or less how they wish in their own posts because *they know best* or because *they own those posts*? If you believe it's the former, a more thorough argument seems warranted.

Comment: Neither. users with enough rep can edit and correct mistakes anyways, but the OPs should be allowed to fail in order to learn/be taught.

Comment: So wait, why are we letting them fail in other areas than just their own posts, in ways that will never give them any feedback? Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: "we can't prevent people from making [bad-decisions]" You can help prevent editors from making bad decisions by not allowing post owner approvals to completely negate any other reject votes on their edits.